# open multiline text file in perl

Tags: perl, variables, multiline

I have the following text file

```
Hello my
name is
Jeff
```

and I want to open it using perl. However, when using this code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt") or die "cannot open input text!";
my $text= <$fh>;
print $text;
```

The output text is only `Hello my`. How can I make it print all of my input text lines and not just the first one ?

Comment: `while (<$fh>){ print;  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In scalar context, evaluating a filehandle in angle brackets yields the next line from that file

so you can use while loop to read the lines (preferred method)

```
while (<$fh>) #output will store into default variable $_
{
    print ; 

}
```

Or you can use the array but you are trying to storing the all content of the file at time in the variable

```
my @array = <$fh>;
```

And the slurp mode to read all file in the scalar variable

```
my $multiline = do { local $/; <$fh>; } #$/ input record seprator
```

Comment: *"When you store the file handle into the scalar variable it will read the next line from the file"* That isn't what happens when you store a file handle in a variable. When you call `readline` on a file handle, maybe.

Comment: *When you store the file handle into the scalar variable it will read the next line from the file* Or as perldoc, more accurately, puts it: "In scalar context, evaluating a filehandle in angle brackets yields the next line from that file".

Comment: @DaveCross and Borodin Thanks for your comment Post edited

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [section on I/O operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2FO-Operators) in [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), you will see the following:

> In scalar context, evaluating a filehandle in angle brackets yields the next line from that file

And, a bit further down:

> If a `<FILEHANDLE>` is used in a context that is looking for a list, a list comprising all input lines is returned, one line per list element.

If you assign `<FILEHANDLE>` to a scalar variable, you will get the next line (actually record) from the file. This is what you are doing:

```
my $text = <$fh>;
```

If you assign `<FILEHANDLE>` to an array, you will get all of the remaining data from the file, with each line (actually record) in a separate element of the array.

```
my @text = <$fh>;
```

If you want to get all data from a file into a scalar, there are a few approaches you can take. The naive approach is to read the data in list context and then join it using an empty string:

```
my $text = join '', <$fh>;
```

You can use `$/` to change Perl's idea of a "record" (often done in a `do` block):

```
my $text = do { local $/; <$fh> };
```

I like [the `slurp` method from Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#slurp,-slurp_raw,-slurp_utf8).

```
use Path::Tiny;

my $text = path($filename)->slurp;
```